# authenticate_user! and allow belongs_to associated devise model to update params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to allow an affiliate devise model to update a users devise models `commission` param.

**I have a User model:**

```
  belongs_to :affiliate, optional: true
```

**And an Affiliate model:**

```
  has_many :users
```

I then have a table for users with forms in which an affiliate or admin can update.  Although,  I would like to keep the `authenticate_user!` but I can't seem to figure it out correctly

**I have tried in the UsersController:**

```
private

def make_sure_affiliate_user
  authenticate_user! || current_affiliates.user
end
```

---

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit, :new, :add_user ]
before_action :make_sure_affiliate_user, :only => [:update]
```

Tried plural or not.

I want an affiliate to be able to change the :commission param on a users tables if the user is associated with.

How can I create that correct association within the method?

For example and instance, I can found orders of an affiliate users with this:

```
Order.all.where(seller: current_affiliate.users )
```

But even that didn't work.

Also, how can I specify the affiliate only being able to update the one param for security purposes?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. Affiliate model has attached devise functionality too? If yes, why don't you use `authenticate_affiliate!` helper? Who is logged in the moment of edit/update - user or affiliate instance?

Comment: Hm good idea but i just tried --- def make_sure_affiliate_user
       authenticate_user! || authenticate_affiliate!
     end --- and it didn't work.  same issue.   also tried --- before_action :authenticate_user! || :authenticate_affiliate!, :only => [ :update, :edit, :new, :add_user ]
 --- same thing.